# How to input a readable text file into my Python code and have it run properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():

    infile = open("studentinfo.txt", "rt")
    data = infile.read()
    fName, lName, ID, year = data.split(",")
    year = int(year)

    # Prompt the user for three test scores
    grades = eval(input("Enter the three test scores separated by a coma: "))
    # Prompt create a username
    uName = (lName[:4] + fName[:2] + str(year)).lower()
    converted_id = ID[:3] + "-" + ID[3:5] + "-" + ID[5:]
    grade_1, grade_2, grade_3 = grades
    # Convert the grades to strings so they can be written to a new file
    [grade_1, grade_2, grade_3] = [str(grade_1), str(grade_2), str(grade_3)]
    # Calculate the average
    average =(float(grade_1) + float(grade_2)+ float(grade_3))/3.0
    # Convert the average to a string
    average = str(average)
    # Write the information to the file
    outfile = open("studentreport.txt", "w")
    outfile.write("*******Student Report*******\nStudent Name:" + fName + " " + lName)
    outfile.write("\nStudent ID:  " + converted_id + "\n" + "Username:    " + uName + "\n\n")
    outfile.write("Grade 1:    " + str(grade_1) + "\n" "Grade 2:    " + str(grade_2) + "\n" + "Grade 3:    " + str(grade_3) + "\n" + "Average:    " + str(average))   

    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

main()
```

How to make it run properly using a readable text file
this is all I get when I run the program help?

```
Enter the three test scores separated by a coma: 80,78,90,
>>> 80,78,90,
(80, 78, 90)
>>> main()
Enter the three test scores separated by a coma: 87,86,90
>>>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is the "studentreport.txt" file not written?

Comment: Tip: don't use `eval(input(...))`; that is really bad practice.

Comment: Uh, what do you want the code to do, and what's the structure of `studentreport.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

There may be some syntax issues, but I cannot test it since I do not have your files, but this may be inline with what you are thinking:

```
def get_grades(student_name):
    grades = raw_input("Enter the three test scores for {0} separated by a coma: ".format(student_name)).split(',')
    if len(grades) != 3:
        print "must enter three grades"
        return get_grades(student_name)
    return float(grades[0]), float(grades[1]), float(grades[2])

with open("studentreport.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("*******Student Report*******\n")
    with open("studentinfo.txt", "r") as infile:
        for student in infile:
            fName, lName, ID, year = student.split(",")
            year = int(year)
            uName = "{0}{1}{2}".format(lName[:4], fName[:2], str(year)).lower()
            converted_id = "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(ID[:3], ID[3:5], ID[5:])

            # Prompt the user for three test scores
            grade_1, grade_2, grade_3 = get_grades("{0} {1}".format(fName, lName))
            average = sum([grade_1, grade_2, grade_3])/3
            outfile.write("Student Name:{0} {1}\n".format(fName, lName))
            outfile.write("Student ID:  {0}\nUsername:    {1}\n\n".format(converted_id, uName))
            outfile.write("Grade 1:    {0}\nGrade 2:    {1}\nGrade 3:    {2}\nAverage:    {3}\n\n".format(grade_1, grade_2, grade_3,average))
```

tested with input:

```
sam, snead, kghasjkdfiuaski21, 2006
john, doe, 9792345678872, 2009
garth, nroken, 097892364, 2006
```

which outputs:

```
*******Student Report*******
Student Name:sam  snead
Student ID:   kg-ha-sjkdfiuaski21
Username:     snesa2006

Grade 1:    56.0
Grade 2:    67.0
Grade 3:    78.0
Average:    67.0

Student Name:john  doe
Student ID:   97-92-345678872
Username:     doejo2009

Grade 1:    67.0
Grade 2:    89.0
Grade 3:    78.0
Average:    78.0

Student Name:garth  nroken
Student ID:   09-78-92364
Username:     nroga2006

Grade 1:    45.0
Grade 2:    67.0
Grade 3:    89.0
Average:    67.0
```

And remember: **Eval is Evil**